# How to make Entity Framework Core create a foreign key constraint that is not enforced

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1, ef-code-first-mapping

I'm using code-first with EF Core 3.1.2

I have established the following two-way one-to-one relationship in the OnModelCreating method of my DbContext.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Inspection>()
    .HasOne<Defect>(i => i.SpecialDefect)
    .WithOne(d => d.SpecialInspection);
```

This creates foreign key constraints in the database.
I would like these constrains to be non-enforced.
i.e. I would like the "Enforce Foreign Key Constraint" option to be set to "No". By default, this is set to yes.

[image]

Is this possible? If so, how might I do this?

Comment: Why do you want this? Is it for performance reasons? Or did the FKs prevent you from adding an `Inspection` without a `SpecialDefect`? The answer to the second problem is *not* to disable the FKs. In SQL, the way to implement the `Inspection<->SpecialDefect` relation would be to add a single `InspectionId` property to `SpecialDefect`.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? In my case I have a Foreign Key value that I don't want to loose when the parent record is deleted. Also I would like to be able to navigate over the *NOT PK* to the parent table.

Comment: In my case, I ended up working around this by changing the way the relationship was implemented in my model. It would be interesting to know how to configure EF Core to set some of these specialised options, though.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to add a row with a NULL value in column "DefectId", you can easily define that as a NULLABLE in the corresponding class.

`public int? DefectId {get;set;}`